# Regex to validate against using a domain-name as the username

Tags: java, regex

I would like to avoid people registering a domainname as the username in my website. What is the good approach to validate against domain names ?

So far i'm doing simple check against .com only :

```
if (username.endsWith(".com")) errorMessage(xxx);
```

But there are other domains like .co.id, etc and other rules about domain names that i'm not aware of. Is it sufficient to match only at the end of the string for a group of internet top-level-domains ?

Comment: does domain name have a fix pattern???

Answer (score 0):

Testing against any kind of domain name is nearly impossible - have you thought about forbidding special characters (`.`, `,`, ...)?

Comment: Do you mind share why it's nearly impossible ? I would like to forbid those special characters, but it seems that it's quite common for widely used services like ggl or fb to allow such characters, and i dont want to break user expectations about it.

Comment: Simply take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains :-)